# Has anyone invested with Privatiers? Is it legitimate?

Tags: investing

Looking for offshore online investments, I stumbled upon [Privatiers](http://www.privatiers.eu/novo/default/en-index.php). It seems to be a Swiss asset management firm.

What I would like to know is if it is legit? Does someone have any experience with them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have a look over the [list of Swiss regulated institutions](http://www.finma.ch/e/beaufsichtigte/bewilligungstraeger/Pages/default.aspx)?

It's worth also mentioning they have [fairly hefty fees](http://www.privatiers.eu/novo/en-products/05a_how_much_do_superior_returns_cost_me.php):

> 1. Closing costs (upfront fee): up to 3.0% of invested capital (according to the cooperation with the local commercial partner / for values greater than $1.000.000 up to 2.0%)
> 2. Annual Administration (management fee): 1.0% of the value "effectively" invested from the managed resources.
> 3. Performance fee (success fee): 20% of annual net profits generated in accordance with the watermark principle.

They're going to have to get extraordinarily good returns to overcome that dead weight.  Maybe they will, [maybe they won't](http://www.economist.com/node/11412714?story_id=11412714).

If your requirement is just for an "offshore online investment" then there are certainly cheaper and arguably safer options.  Open a brokerage account in a country of your choice, and buy a local-total-stockmarket ETF, gold, or bonds.  Or see one of the several [other questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/913/how-easy-is-it-to-open-a-foreign-bank-account-via-the-internet) about opening a foreign bank account.

Comment: I couldn't find them in the Swiss list of regulated institutions. Thanks for the analysis though. Better stay clear.

Answer (score 6):

See:
http://www.privatiers.eu/novo/en-products/01_constant_earnings_with_absolute_return.php

When people sell securities with absolute, constant, high returns, they are usually crooked or ignorant.